# Why is `ref None` value restricted in Ocaml?

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml

The value restriction rule says that generalization can only occur if the right-hand side of an expression is syntactically a value.

I don't understand why `let r = ref None` is value restricted? 
How come `ref (Some 2)` is a value and `ref None` is not?

Is it the case that `None` is like a type constructor? `None` is not a value? It seems to me that `None` is a polymorphic value. Is there any such thing as polymorphic value?

It seems to me that value restriction occurs when there is some sort of interaction with multiple polymorphic entities like `id id` or `ref None`.

I am a beginner to OCaml doing self study. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `ref None` is a value (and so is `ref (Some 2)` ...). The value restriction rule is about types. Typing happens at compile time. Values exist at runtime.

Comment: what I read was here http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction that ref None is not a value.

Comment: I am going through the more precise definition of a syntactic value given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149525/why-id-id-is-not-a-value-in-ocaml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutable state *must not* be polymorphic. The ref case is the reason why the value restriction exists in the first place. Consider:

```
let r = ref None in     (* consider this was r : 'a option ref *)
r := Some "boo";        (* then this would be well-typed *)
unSome (!r) + 1         (* and this would be well-typed as well -- BOOM! *)
```

where unSome is a helper:

```
let unSome = function Some x -> x | None -> raise Not_found
```

Answer (score 4):

Neither `ref None` nor `ref (Some 2)` is a value in the sense used for the value restriction. Both of them are *applications* of the function `ref`.

It doesn't make sense to talk about generalizing `ref (Some 2)` as there is no possible polymorphism.

`None` is a value but `ref None` is not a value (in the syntactic sense used for the value restriction). Since `None` is a value it can be generalized (so it's polymorphic):

```
# let my_none = None;;
val my_none : 'a option = None

# let f x = if x then Some 3 else my_none;;
val f : bool -> int option = <fun>
# let g x = if x then Some "abc" else my_none;;
val g : bool -> string option = <fun>
```

Since `my_none` is polymorphic it can function as a value of type `int option` and also as a value of type `string option`.

**Update**

OCaml has a "relaxed" value restriction whereby some things that are not syntactic values can still be generalized (made polymorphic).

You can read about the relaxed value restriction in this paper, which I often cite. (I also reread it periodically because I tend to forget the argument over time.)

[Jacques Garrigue, Relaxing the Value Restriction](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/garrigue-value_restriction-fiwflp04.pdf)

Comment: Ok, That makes sense, So take away here is notion of value in value restriction is that of a "syntactic value" and we would not consider function applications as a syntactic value since they do some computation.

Comment: Although, I wonder why something like `ref None` is not a syntactic value, and something like `id None` is? where `let id = fun x -> x`

Comment: `id None` is not a syntactic value. It's an application of the function `id`. However, OCaml has a *relaxed* value restriction. There is an excellent paper to read about this; I'll add the link to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help.